# how to separate "/" in SQL REGEX

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to get rows that the urls contain one or more chinese character.I write a sql with regexp to do it.But i failed because the "/" fits the regexp.

The regexp is

```
SELECT "/" REGEXP '.*[^\x0f-\xff].*'
```

and the Sequel Pro returns 1

However, I find a pro-reg-testing-website to do the same regexp and it turns out 0.

Why it acts different with the same regexp in that website and the Sequel Pro?If the website has some optimization on it, then how to make it in the Sequel?

Comment: Well, [you know](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html): "The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with multibyte character sets.". You appear to be using some single-byte encoding though but you don't consider it relevant enough to mention which one so I guess that's the root problem: a byte, without context, can mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE HEX(str) REGEXP '^(..)*E[3456789ABCD]';
```

will check for a variety of CJK characters.  (This assumes `str` is `CHARACTER SET utf8` or `utf8mb4`.)  This may include Japanese and Korean characters, too.

I'm digging around for the 'extension' characters; seems like they begin with `F0`.

**EDIT**

Well, it turns out that Chinese is all over the place:

```
REGEXP
'^(..)*E2B[AB]|E380|E387|E38[89AB]|E38[CDEF]|E[34][9AB][0-9A-F]|E[456789]B[89ABCDEF]|EFA[456789AB]|EFB[89]|F0A[0123456789A][89][0-9A-F]|F0A[AB]9C|F0AB[9A][DEF0]|F0A[BC][AB][0-9A-F]|F0AFA[012345678]'
```

Comment: I think the revised regexp isn't quite right; maybe I will work on it later.